# Joins table parent to another joins table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design, data-structures

I'm planning the following table:

[image]

While I know this is technically feasible (I just tried it), I wanted to see if it seemed unnecessarily complicated... Basically I'm keeping track of revenues vs. costs.

`Tab1` contains revenue data for both `Tab2` & `Tab3`. `Tab2` contains its own cost data, so that's easy. But the complication is that `Tab3` costs are further allocated across `Tab2` units. That's why there's a secondary `joinsB` table there.

I realize this isn't a concrete question, but I know there are so many more experienced folks who, based on that experience, will have a gut "wow this is too complicated" sense or not about what I'm doing. That's what I'd like input/ feedback on as a gut check before I build this.

**EDIT for more clarity**

- Tab1 = Charges
- Tab2 = Reservations
- Tab3 = Logistics
- joinsA = TypeCharges
- joinsB = TypeLogistics

A user pays for a `reservation` of something, but may also pay to have that something shipped `logistically`. The two payments are wrapped up in one `charge`. The complication is that one `logistics` shipment may contain  more than 1 `reservation` under separate users (i.e., separate `charges`).

This data structure is designed to help me do two things:

- easily track exactly which `charge` is associated with a given `reservation` or `logistics` so that for example I can issue a refund, but for a specific amount (for example, a user may keep the `reservation` but want to cancel the `logistics` shipment and pay for it him/herself using another vendor)
- easily understand how the cost of a `logistics` breaks down into allocatable costs by `reservation`

The latter is why Tab3 and Tab2 are joined, and the through table contains more information on the nature of the type of logistics. The through table also contains the `charge` amount that the user paid to have a `reservation` shipped `logistically`. Tab3 contains the cost of the `logistics` which is then allocated based on how many `reservations` there are. Then you can compare that allocated cost against the `charge` for the specific reservation in the joins table.

Comment: You say "Tab3 costs are further allocated across Tab2 units" - what does a "unit" mean in this case? Could you provide the table structures? Do all 3 tables have revenue and costs for such "units"? Need some more information to help answer this.

Comment: Added some more detail, hopefully that helps? I'm sorry this particular thing is very hard for me to explain... feel free to ask questions @vmachan

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to track your charges at reservation + logistics level. If I were to model this I would do it as shown in the below diagram where the Reservations is an entity/table and so is Logistics. These have a many-to-many relation with each other, this is many-to-many relation is materialized using the Charges entity/table. So if you need charges for a reservation, you add up all the charges for a reservation, if you need charges for a logistic you add up all the charges for a logistic/shipment. The base data in the Charges table will contain the lowest level of granularity of the charges and can be rolled up by reservation and/or logistic/shipment.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your input! Different than what I'm ultimately doing but had some helpful nuggets that pointed me in the right direction. What makes this exercise challenging is that I'm trying to find something that works technically, but is also efficient operationally and enables easy financial accounting. Juggling multiple functions!